# How to validate a textarea for not allowing spaces between words

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi is there any way to restrict the textarea without spaces between two words

Comment: Using the keydown event you can prevent the spacebar key from being entered but seeig text can be copy-pasted into textareas you would have a hard time preventing that. A better solution would be to let the user enter what they like and strip the spaces out before saving the text or even on the `blur` event. Assuming that is the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this simple jquery can help

html

```
<textarea></textarea>
<span id="adf" style="display:none; color:red">No space allowed and use comma to seperate</span>
```

Jquery

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        $('#adf').css("display", "block");
        return false;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#adf').slideUp('slow');
    }, 5000);
});
```

here is fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/H688j/2/)

Comment: cool execution on this Arish.  I went with keydown() just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good example here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeydown

You need to handle keydown event and return false if the key is not appropriate.
According to your situation the following code may be used:

```
<input type="text" value="QQ" onkeydown="return keydownHandler(event)"/>
```

And JS part will be

```
function keydownHandler(event)
{
    var keynum;
    var keychar;
    var numcheck;

    if(window.event) // IE8 and earlier
    {
        keynum = event.keyCode;
    }
    else if(event.which) // IE9/Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Safari
    {
        keynum = event.which;
    }

    keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    numcheck = / /;
    return !numcheck.test(keychar);             
}
```